# restore deleted temporary layer while QGIS is still running

Tags: qgis

I have accidentally overwritten an important shapefile and some of my data seem to be lost now. However, I hope there is a way to restore some of it: I have run "count in polygons" tool recently on the by then still original shapefile in question. Unfortunately, I removed the result which was only stored in temporary layer. Is there a way to restore this temporary layer? I haven't closed QGIS (2.18), so I hope the respective layer is not deleted.

Comment: did you use Processing to create the temporary layer? Or was it one you created with "Layer>Create Temporary Layer>Create Scratch Layer" (or using the usual QGIS menu options and "temporary file" as output)? And if Processing, what OS are you using (Win/Linux/Mac)?

Comment: It was processing and I use Win 10.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. I did a test with a temporary output and defined the layer using `layer = iface.activeLayer()` and source using `source = layer.source()` (which was `u'Polygon?uuid=cc8106aa-6f9b-4021-876d-d378c8d9ad05&crs=EPSG:4326&field=Processed:string&field=a:string&field=NUMPOINTS:integer'`. I removed the layer and tried to define a new one using: `newLayer = QgsVectorLayer(source, 'Name', 'ogr')`. I tried to load it, access its data etc but nothing. So my guess is that the data stored in memory gets wiped when you remove it from the `QgsMapLayerRegistry`.

Comment: tahnk you for the help, @Joseph. This didn't work out for me neither. However, I found an earlier version of the layer so I could restore it with a reasonable amount of effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't think this suggestion will help in your case, but I offer it in the hope that it might help avoid problems like this in future.

There's a plugin called **Memory Layer Saver** ([more info](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MemoryLayerSaver/)) which stores **vector** memory layers alongside your QGIS project.

- get in the habit of saving your project often
- before you save your project, run the plugin (**Plugins > Memory Layer Saver > Display Memory Layer Information**) so that it finds any new memory layers
- save your project

Now, if you delete a vector memory layer by mistake, and realise it immediately, you can close the QGIS project (without saving) and reopen it, and the layer will come back.

I don't think this will work in your case, as the plugin won't "see" layers which you have already removed from the legend.

Comment: This is a good proposal, @Steven Kay. I will definitely get in the habit of saving everything as often (and also backed up) as I can. QGIS also crashes sometimes without offering any "restore-option" when running it again. So I already do save very regularly; in this case however I made a big mistake by overwriting an important layer with a newer version which accidentally had lost most of its features by processing it.
So the memory layer saver seems a good option for me now!